# Better solution for lower-casing Java Enum constants in Jackson

Tags: jackson

I'm looking for a better (more terse) solution for having capitalized Java enum constants serialized/deserialized as lower-case in Jackson than this boilerplate code:

```
    public enum GitLabPipelineStatusEnum {
        
        @JsonProperty("canceled")
        CANCELED,
        
        @JsonProperty("created")
        CREATED,
        
        @JsonProperty("failed")
        FAILED,
        
        @JsonProperty("manual")
        MANUAL,
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```java
public enum GitLabPipelineStatusEnum {
   
    CANCELED,
    CREATED,
    FAILED,
    MANUAL,

    @JsonValue
    public String toLowerCase() {
        return toString().toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

## Reference

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums